# Image Picker in SwiftUI - how do I know when the user has chosen an image in the hosting UIkit based ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As I add new features to an existing UIKit based project, i am atempting to write any new views using SwiftUI.

However I have ran into an issue, and im not sure what the best practice is to achive what I need to do.

I have created a SwiftUI view thats hosted in a UIHostingController from an existing ViewController.

The Swift UI view is essential and Image and Button that then allows the user to pick an image from UIPickerViewController

```
struct PenPicUploader: View {
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State var image: Image?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                if let image = image {
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(
                            Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                } else {
                    Image("person")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(
                            Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingImagePicker = true
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        Color("accent4")
                            .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .opacity(0.6)
                            .frame(width: 46, height: 46, alignment: .center)
                            .overlay(
                                Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .background(Color.clear)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("accent1"))
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center)
                    }.position(x: getWidth(geometry: geometry)-13, y: getHeight(geometry: geometry)-13)
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage)
            }
        }
    }

    func getWidth(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let frame = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        return frame.size.width
    }

    func getHeight(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let frame = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        return frame.size.height
    }

    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    }
}
```

This is backed up with an ImagePicker UIViewControllerRepresentable

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    let parent: ImagePicker

    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            parent.image = uiImage
        }
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

How do I get to know the user has picked an image in the UIKit viewcontroller ? Do i need delgates ? or some other more SwiftUI approach to this ?

Comment: *How do I get to know...* - why do you need that?

Comment: I need to save the Image to an API which is handled by another class. Could I simply put it in the UIViewControllerRepresentable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was as simple as putting the call to the Api call in the picker call back in  UIViewControllerRepresentable

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        parent.image = uiImage
        apiHelper.uploadProfileImage(imageToUpload: uiImage) { (success, _) in
            if success {
                print("IMAGE UPLOADED")
            } else {
                print("IMAGE UPLOAD FAILED")
            }
        }

    }
    parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `.onChange(of:)` modifier, like

```
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
        ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage)
    }
    .onChange(of: image) {
        if let img = $0 {
            // call save here with new image `img`
        }
    }
```